# Passing Write-Host color parameter to a function

Tags: function, parameters, colors, write-host

I want to pass a color parameter to a function to display a message in different colors

```
function WriteLogColor {
    param ([String]$Msg,
            $Color)
    $TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format "dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"
 
    Write-Host "[$TimeStamp] $Msg" -ForegroundColor $Color
}
```

When calling
`WriteLogColor("Hello World", Red)`
, the syntax is not correct.

Is it a way to pass a parameter to this function to display strings in different colors ?

Thanks